# How to resize a linux partition while the system is running?

Tags: filesystems, opensuse

The filesystem of one of our VMs (running OpenSUSE LEAP 15.3) which had initially been set up with 10GB only ran full. So I extended it in vSphere by 20GB. Following a description that I had found I then first created a new partition `/dev/sda3` from the 20GB at the end of that disk:

```
~ # fdisk -l   

Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000845f1

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  1026047  1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1026048 20971519 19945472  9.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       20971520 62914559 41943040   20G 83 Linux
~ #
```

But then I got doubts. I think it would actually be better to remove that newly created partition again and instead extend the already existing `/dev/sda2`.

How can I do that best and easiest? I.e. how can I remove `/dev/sda3` again and change `/dev/sda2`'s end sector to 62914559 instead? The issue for me is that I need to do that from the running VM itself without corrupting the filesystem.
I.e. I can't boot this system from a CD or memory stick containing some partition editing tool but need to do that while the system is running. I guess that's possible but I am obviously not a Linux crack, so please bear with me!

In case that's relevant here: `/dev/sda2` is formatted using btrfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The lazy way: using btrfs features to merge `sda3` into the existing filesystem

If you only care about the results (i.e. getting the disk capacity of the partition `sda3` to become part of the existing filesystem), you can simply do this:

(assuming that `sda2` is your root filesystem, and the filesystem you actually want to extend)

```
btrfs device add /dev/sda3 /   # this makes the new capacity available
```

then

```
btrfs filesystem balance /     # this optimizes things but can take a long time
```

And you are done.

Yes, a single `btrfs` filesystem can occupy multiple partitions.

---

### The thorough way: actually removing the `sda3` partition and extending `sda2`

First, you'll need to remove the `sda3` partition you created. If you haven't yet mounted it, added it into an existing `btrfs` nor otherwise put it into use, you can simply run `fdisk /dev/sda`, then enter `d` for "delete partition", then `3` for the number of partition to delete, and finally `w` to write the changes to disk and exit `fdisk`.

Then run `cat /proc/partitions` and make sure there is no more `sda3` listed: if there is, run `partprobe /dev/sda` and check again.

The easiest tool for extending existing partitions is probably `growpart`. It doesn't seem to be available as standard on OpenSuSE 15.3, but apparently you can get it from here: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=Cloud%3ATools&package=growpart

To extend the `sda2` partition to take up any contiguous unpartitioned free space located after it on the disk:

```
growpart /dev/sda 2
```

Then to resize the `btrfs` filesystem to fill the now-larger partition: (assuming `sda2` is your root filesystem)

```
btrfs filesystem resize max /
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very precise and concrete description. Highly appreciated! I intend to take the second option but will need to install  "growpart" first.

Comment: BTW: worked like a charm! Thanks again!